# Run restart class without xml file in background if i run this it will run Blank Activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

After restart this class is used for run when mobile is restart

```
public class BootUpReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, Restart.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);

    }

}
```

After restart Java class this class is run but it will show blank xml i donot want any xml only want to run this code in background please help me

```
public class Restart extends Activity {
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    String name, password,serial;
    EditText EtU, EtP;
    String user;
    String passwordgui;
    Cursor d, e;
       // TextView t1,t2;
    String getSimSerialNumber ;
    String getSimOperator;
    String IMEINumber;
    TelephonyManager telemamanger;
    @Override
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      // setContentView(R.layout.restart);
     //   LinearLayout rlayout1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
       // setVisibility(View.GONE);
      // rlayout1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        db = openOrCreateDatabase("abb", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

        telemamanger = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        getSimSerialNumber = telemamanger.getSimSerialNumber();

       // t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_1);
       // t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_2);

        d = db.rawQuery("SELECT serial from ta2", null);

        d.moveToFirst();

        serial = d.getString(d.getColumnIndex("serial"));

       // t1.setText("DB " + serial.toString());
       // t2.setText(getSimSerialNumber.toString());

        if(IsValid())
        {
            WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
            SystemClock.sleep(9000);


            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "You information successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();

        }
        String fromEmail = "111820050@umt.edu.pk";
        String fromPassword = "pakistan1919";
        String toEmails ="ahmadtahirpictures@gmail.com"; // from database later
        List<String> toEmailList = Arrays.asList(toEmails
                .split("\\s*,\\s*"));
        Log.i("SendMailActivity", "To List: " + toEmailList);
        String emailSubject = "Mobile restrt";
        String emailBody =  "SIM Number: ";

        new SendMailTask(Restart.this).execute(fromEmail, fromPassword, toEmailList, emailSubject, emailBody);

    }
    private boolean IsValid()
    {
        if(serial.toString().equals(getSimSerialNumber.toString()) )
            return true;
        else
           return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: run in background. I don't think you need activity for that. Use a service (intent service)

Comment: please brother tell me what i do i try but fail

Comment: this code work if mobile restart or sim change it will send email or message

Comment: you need to start a service not an activity, an activity will display something even if it is blank

Comment: Thanks Pankaj Nimgade and Raghunandan  please tell how to start services in this code or restart class...